# Is there an example of a revolute2 (double hinge) joint used in an SDF?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am looking for an example about how to use a revolute2 joint. I do not find any in tutorials. Only simple hinges.

I am a bit confused about who is the child and who is the parent link (suppose a car steering wheel) and how are both axes  values in the same reference frame?

Thank you,

David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16518/is-there-an-example-of-a-revolute2-(double-hinge)-joint-used-in-an-sdf?/) by [dbrodeur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3119/dbrodeur/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-06-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The [Demo Joint Types](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/pull-requests/241) model includes an example of a revolute2 joint. The revolute2 joint behaves like two revolute joints in series with a zero-length link between them.

I'm not confident about this, but I think the first axis is relative to the `<parent>`, and the second axis is relative to the `<child>`.

When you say car steering wheel do you mean the wheel someone puts their hands on to steer the car, or one of the steerable wheels that rolls on the ground? If the former I would use a revolute joint instead of a revolute2 joint since there's only one axis it can rotate on. If the latter I would make the car body the parent and car tire the child, because the joint pose would be in the center of the wheel by default.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbrodeur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3119/dbrodeur/) on 2017-06-26**:
Thanks for the Demo Joint Types! That should help me. About the steering wheel, I meant the latter option. I am trying to do an updated version of the mobile_robot tutorial using revolute2 joints. Just to understand better this type of joints. Thanks again for the demo joint types model.

**Comment by [wicked88](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2759/wicked88/) on 2017-08-16**:
@dbrodeur any luck controlling the revolute2 joint ? I'm trying to build a car and the front wheels need to rotate in two axes obviously. Tho, in my plugin it seems im not able to control any of the axes ... If i try to set the position using JointPtr->SetPosition(index, value) with various indexes, they all return false.